# How can I make this function more efficient/ run it parallel?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, arcgis

I am trying to convert 33000 zipcodes into coordinates using geocoder package. I was hoping there was a way to parallelize this method because it is consuming quite a bit of resources.

```
from geopy.geocoders import ArcGIS
import pandas as pd
import time
geolocator = ArcGIS()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=list(range(0,len(df))), columns=list(['lat','lon']))
df = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1)
for index in range(0,len(df)):
      row = df['zipcode'].loc[index]
      print index
#      time.sleep(1) 
#    I put this function in just in case it would give me a timeout error. 
      myzip = geolocator.geocode(row)
      try: 
        df['lat'].loc[index] = myzip.latitude
        df['lon'].loc[index] = myzip.longitude
      except: 
        continue
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Use a different language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here would be one way to do it, using `multiprocessing.Pool`

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_longlat(x):
    index, row = x
    print index
    time.sleep(1)
    myzip = geolocator.geocode(row['zipcode'])
    try:
        return myzip.latitude, myzip.longitude
    except:
        return None, None

p = Pool()
df[['lat', 'long']] = p.map(get_longlat, df.iterrows())
```

More generally, using `DataFrame.iterrows` (for which each item iterated over is an index, row tuple) is likely slightly more efficient than the index-based method you use above

EDIT: after reading the other answer, you should be aware of rate limiting; you could use a fix number of processes in the `Pool` along with a `time.sleep` delay to mitigate this to some extent, however.

Answer (score 2):

`geopy.geocoders.ArcGIS.geocode` queries a web server. Sending 33,000 queries alone will probably get you IP banned, so I wouldn't suggest sending them in parallel.

You're looking up almost every single ZIP code in the US. The US Census Bureau has a 1MB CSV file that contains this information for 33,144 ZIP codes: https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/gazetteer2017.html.

You can process it all in a fraction of a second:

```
zip_df = pd.read_csv('2017_Gaz_zcta_national.zip', sep='\t')
zip_df.rename(columns=str.strip, inplace=True)
```

One thing to watch out for is that the last column's name isn't properly parsed by Pandas and contains a lot of trailing whitespace. You have to strip the column names before use.